# AngularJS: Custom directive HTML attribute 'not defined'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[I wrote a custom directive to implement a button toggle](http://plnkr.co/edit/SXWru38TfkLl7I682gOA?p=preview).  When I interact with the button and confirm that I want to toggle it, I get `Uncaught Reference Error: on is not defined`.  I thought that I defined `on` as an HTML attribute in the custom `<button-toggle></button-toggle>` element.  The reason for my concern is because I may want to send the value of `on` or `off` to the server.  Where am I going wrong?

**buttonToggle.html**

```
<div class="btn-group btn-toggle">
    <button class="btn btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-success':on, 'btn-default':!on}">ON</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-danger':off, 'btn-default':!off}">OFF</button>
</div>
```

**buttonToggle.js**

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('buttonToggle', buttonToggle);

function buttonToggle() {

    function link(scope, elm, attr, ctrl){

        angular.element(elm).on('click', function(){

            var confirmResponse = (window.confirm("Are you sure?") === true);

            if( confirmResponse ) {
                  scope.on = !scope.on;
                  scope.off = !scope.off;
                 scope.$digest();
                if(on)
                    return off;
                else if(off)
                    return on;
            }

             scope.$digest();
        });
    }

    var directive = {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: link,
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'buttonToggle.html',
        scope: {
            on: "=",
            off: "="
        }
    };

    return directive;
}
```

**buttonToggleCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('buttonToggleCtrl', buttonToggleCtrl);

function buttonToggleCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.activeOn = true;
  $scope.activeOff = false;
}
```

**index.html snippet**

```
<button-toggle on="activeOn" off="activeOff"></button-toggle>
```

As a note, don't worry about how the button looks right now.  I know it's messed up in the plnkr, but it looks fine in my app since I'm using Bootstrap there and not in the plnkr.  Pay attention to the error being throw in the JavaScript console.

Comment: no need to wrap `elm` in `angular.element()` ... it's already done when passed to `link`. Can just do `elm.on('click'..`

Comment: also doesn't make sense toggling 2 boolean variables when only one is needed

Comment: @charlietfl Both of those make sense, I'll be sure to change them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you passed your directive code through any static checker like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/), you would notice the culprits:

```
if(on)
    return off;
else if(off)
    return on;
```

You should use `scope.on` and `scope.off` in these four lines instead.

Comment: Ahh, worked nicely.  I need to setup JSHint in my grunt build.  Thanks.